# Hartl Rails Tutorial Chap.11.1.2 test issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

Having an issue at the beginning of Chap 11. After testing green at the end of Chap 10, I added Listing 11.2 to tests/models/micropost_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'
```

class MicropostTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

```
def setup
    @users = users(:michael)
    # This code not idiomatically correct.
    @micropost = Micropost.new(content: "Lorem ipsum", user_id: @user.id)
end

test "should be valid" do
    assert @micropost.valid?
end

test "user id should be present" do
    @micropost.user_id = nil
    assert_not @micropost.valid?
end
```

end

and predictably got a RED. Added the validations from Listing 11.4 to app/model/s/micropost.rb `

class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   validates :user_id, presence: true
end

The problem is that I continue to get the following errors on test:

ERROR["test_should_be_valid", MicropostTest, 0.255918787]
 test_should_be_valid#MicropostTest (0.26s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
            test/models/micropost_test.rb:8:in`setup'
        test/models/micropost_test.rb:8:in `setup'

ERROR["test_user_id_should_be_present", MicropostTest, 0.260151448]
 test_user_id_should_be_present#MicropostTest (0.26s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
            test/models/micropost_test.rb:8:in`setup'
        test/models/micropost_test.rb:8:in `setup'

Can anyone steer me in the right direction? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is in this line :

```
@users = users(:michael)
```

It should be @user without s

```
@user = users(:michael)
```

because you are using that variable @user in this line

```
@micropost = Micropost.new(content: "Lorem ipsum", user_id: @user.id)
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the NoMethodError, but I am now failing the test for a valid micropost, which tells me it somehow is not seeing the user_id. I've re-checked my code after the correction and still cant find the culprit! FAIL["test_should_be_valid", MicropostTest, 0.762289534]
 test_should_be_valid#MicropostTest (0.76s)
        Failed assertion, no message given.
        test/models/micropost_test.rb:12:in `block in <class:MicropostTest>'

Comment: @BertRamirez where is the error which says that is not seeing the user_id ?  by doing `@micropost = Micropost.new(content: "Lorem ipsum", user_id: @user.id)`  you should permit :content and :user_id in your strong parameters in the controller to make your test pass; something like `params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :user_id)`

Comment: Sorry...here is the error.... FAIL["test_should_be_valid", MicropostTest, 0.744022407]
 test_should_be_valid#MicropostTest (0.74s)
        Failed assertion, no message given.
        test/models/micropost_test.rb:12:in `block in <class:MicropostTest>'

Comment: Also, I should add, at the beginning of Chapter 11, he has us generate the test first, which will fail until the model is generated, when it is supposed to pass. Still no controller generated at this point in the tutorial..

Comment: @BertRamirez I am not sure where the error comes from,  as I understand from your error message, the source of your problem is this line `assert @micropost.valid?` right ? if so I am really not sure why because the brevious code seems correct ! please continue reading through the chapter, maybe you can find the solution

Comment: Found the underlying problem!! Checked my gemlist agains the reference on github and found I still had a gem called "protected_attributes"....once I uninstalled it ALL my tests passed and I could finally remove the old "attributes_accessible line from my users model and everything clicked into place... now on to the next challenge! Thank you for your help!!

Comment: @BertRamirez Great, attributes_accessible was used in rails 3, in rails 4 it's deprecated and strong parameters is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Answer turned out to be that I had an old "protected_attributes" gem installed. You cant use it AND strong parameters. Once I uninstalled, I could remove the old attributes_accessible line from my model and all tests passed.